Qt QModel view use QSortFilterProxyModel fucntion is so slow，something wrong？
I use Qt Model view with QSortFilterProxyModel
QListView with checkbox and name ，only one column
QStandardItemModel setData ,100w row
use QSortFilterProxyModel function setFilterFixedString
and add a function changed all row checkbox checked
like this in my class Inheritance QStandardItemModel
void toggleAllItemsInModel(QStandardItemModel* model, bool checked)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < model->rowCount(); ++i) {
        QStandardItem* item = model->item(i);
        if (item && item->isCheckable()) {
            item->setCheckState(checked ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
        }
}

my question is this function toggleAllItemsInModel only use 0.1s ，but setFilterFixedString use more than 12s，why this function is so slow and i think Qt model view has been optimized view show, i need optimize,please give some advice.
i use modelItem userole + 1 save hidden mark ,and add function filterAccptsRow,but alse use 12s,
set DynamicSortFilter(false), and setFilterRole(Qt::DisplayRole),but no use.
a better function is not use QSortFilterProxyModel and realizing in QStandardItemModel?
this is test code like my code.
Only two function selectAll and filterString.
use Qt5.15,CentOS Linux 7,release version test
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QVBoxLayout>
#include <QListView>
#include <QStandardItemModel>
#include <QSortFilterProxyModel>
#include <QLineEdit>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QCheckBox>

    class CheckableStandardItemModel : public QStandardItemModel {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        CheckableStandardItemModel(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QStandardItemModel(parent) {
        setColumnCount(1);
    }
    
    
        // select all checkbox 
        void selectAll(bool select) {
            beginResetModel();
            for (int row = 0; row < rowCount(); ++row) {
                QStandardItem *item = item(row, 0);
                if (item) {
                    item->setCheckState(select ? Qt::Checked : Qt::Unchecked);
                }
            }
            endResetModel();
        }
    };
    
    class TestWindow : public QWidget {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        TestWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr) : QWidget(parent) {
            setupUi();
            setupModel();
            setupProxyModel();
            connectSignals();
        }
    
    private:
        QListView *listView;
        CheckableStandardItemModel *model;
        QSortFilterProxyModel *proxyModel;
        QLineEdit *filterLineEdit;
        QPushButton *filterButton;
        QCheckBox *selectAllCheckbox;
    
        void setupUi() {
            QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
            listView = new QListView(this);
            filterLineEdit = new QLineEdit(this);
            filterButton = new QPushButton("Filter", this);
            selectAllCheckbox = new QCheckBox("Select All", this);
            layout->addWidget(listView);
            layout->addWidget(filterLineEdit);
            layout->addWidget(filterButton);
            layout->addWidget(selectAllCheckbox);
        }
    
        void setupModel() {
            model = new CheckableStandardItemModel(this);
            model->setHorizontalHeaderLabels(QStringList("Name"));
            for(int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i) {
                QStandardItem *item = new QStandardItem(QString("Item%1").arg(i));
                item->setCheckable(true);
    
                model->appendRow(item);
            }
        }
    
        void setupProxyModel() {
            proxyModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
            proxyModel->setSourceModel(model);
            proxyModel->setFilterCaseSensitivity(Qt::CaseInsensitive);
            listView->setModel(proxyModel);
        }
    
        void connectSignals() {
            connect(filterLineEdit, &QLineEdit::textChanged, this, [this](const QString& text) {
                //test time here
                proxyModel->setFilterFixedString(text);
            });
            connect(selectAllCheckbox, &QCheckBox::stateChanged, this, [this](int state) {
                //test time here
                model->selectAll(state == Qt::Checked);
                listView->viewport()->update();
            });
        }
    };
    
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        QApplication app(argc, argv);
        TestWindow window;
        window.show();
        return app.exec();
    }


Please show a [mre]. Are you running in debug or release?

@ Alan Birtles
add test code.

are you using debug or release?

Setting the checkstate or changing a filter is not the same thing (especially considering the amount of items you have). Also, please use functions appropriately: beginResetModel() and endResetModel() are to be used when the model is actually reset or as an alternative to dataChanged(): since you're using QStandardItemModel, that makes it completely useless, since it will emit dataChanged anyway when doing setCheckState(), unless you block its signals. It should also be unnecessary to update the viewport (if things are done appropriately).

thanks，my real code and beginResetModel,and endResetModel function, and i add  blocksignal function. And i think save checked state and filter item to hidden can be save with

thanks，my real code has used beginResetModel,and endResetModel function, and I add  blocksignal(true) function. And i think save checked state and filter item to hidden can be save with bool ,and check function can be same. In my new code,Not use QSortFilterProxyModel,I add myTestModel: public QStandardItem, add fiter function in data(),rowCount(), this is faster like selectAllCheckbox(), about 0.2s.

@Alan Birtles use release version

I edit this question，but it still close，who can open and continue？

@codeTestUser 1. please use @username; 2. you have a very large model: setting a simple flag for each of them is one thing, checking the display value, matching it with a regex and eventually remove/restore the index for one million entries is quite different. Maybe you should consider using a database, and implement the filter with standard SQL queries.

@musicamante thanks, My new code  remove QSortFilterProxyModel and only use QStandardItemModel. I inherit from the QStandardItemModel  class and modify the data() setData() rowCount() method and add some update functions.it is better than QSortFilterProxyModel. Maybe QSortFilterProxyModel offers more features but is slower as a result.
